# Can I create Microsoft Teams online meetings on behalf of guest users using Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to be able to create online meetings on behalf of users added to Azure AD that do not belong to the registered tenant of Azure (so the user has a guest account):

```
xyz_gmail.com#EXT#@tenant_here0
```

I cannot do this via the V1.0 API (create event) because I get "Office 365 REST API not enabled" - which is because the user doesn't have it enabled.

I cannot do this via the beta API (create online meeting) because I get "user "GUID_HERE" cannot be found or does not belong to the tenant." when trying to add the policy via Powershell (Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy)

Is there a way to create online meetings on behalf of these guest users that I am not seeing?

Comment: You cannot create a meeting on behalf user but you can create the meeting to user calendar using User principal name/ user id. You can user id by using get list user API. Please check this docs [create event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) and [list users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Comment: That means I have to create the event as one of the registered tenant accounts and then that user will have to start the meeting right? - This also means that that admin is the only one to admit attendees too?

Comment: What do you want to do? Create event or create online meeting? I'm a little confused because you mentioned both of them in your post.

Comment: An online meeting (you can do so via the event)

Comment: What im really trying to do is to be able to have users register and be able to create online meetings between them and other users - the users registered will be guest Azure AD accounts (not owned by the tenant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all expected results that [online meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions) cannot be created from a guest.

[image]
1.Creating online meeting by microsoft social account(guest account),Failed.

2.Creating online meeting by microsoft social account(guest account),but now it added into tenant and belong to ******work or school account***(Global admin role)***,Failed.

***UPDATE***

Although Guest users have the same access as members(most inclusive),it still does not work.
[image]

Comment: This is what I thought - appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: ~I was really hoping the "Guest users has the same access as members" meant it could be done :(

Comment: I'm glad this can help you!Currently, this is not supported:)